# show result of action in new place (without use of $this->layout()->content; )

Tags: zend-framework, layout, view

```
<?php echo $this->layout()->content; ?>
```

The code above results in `$this->layout()->content` being shown in every place in layout file. But i need granularity to show the result of some actions in another place (E.g. in a right column or left column).

This is layout file:

```
<div class="center_col"><?php echo $this->layout()->content; ?></div>
<div class="right_col">?????</div>
```

How i can show result of some actions in the provided (above) `.right_col` ?

Comment: Could you take a step back and look at your question again and rewrite it? I am trying, but I *really* cannot make sense of what you are asking.

Comment: Possible dublicate of this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1627962/how-do-i-include-header-and-footer-with-layout-in-zend-framework

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way would be to define your own layout placeholders (i.e. other than 'content'). For example:

```
<div class="center_col"><?php echo $this->layout()->content; ?></div>
<div class="right_col"><?php echo $this->layout()->rightColumn; ?></div>
```

Then in your action you need to tell the Zend_Layout to use the new content placeholder, e.g.:

```
public function testAction() { 
    // ....
    // render output of this action in 'rightColumn' placeholder
    // rather than in default 'content' placeholder.      
    $this->view->layout()->setContentKey('rightColumn');            
}
```

Alternatively, you could also have a look at [placeholder](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.view.helpers.html#zend.view.helpers.initial.placeholder) view helper. With the helper, you could do e.g.:

```
<div class="center_col"><?php echo $this->layout()->content; ?></div>
<div class="right_col"><?php echo $this->placeholder('right_col'); ?></div>
```

The helper has many functions that can ease management of its content.

Hope this will be helpful.

Comment: thanx Marcin , perfect like ever ;)

Comment: @Marcin Wouldn't the first code example (adding $this->layout()->rightcolumn) require you to add this to every controller?