# Zend Framework 2 - How to include partial from library

Tags: php, partial-views, zend-framework2, zend-view, view-helpers

I wrote a partial which I want to use in several modules. I thought the best way would be to put it into my custom library.

But unfortunately I couldn't figure out a way to include this partial without using a very ugly path like:

```
echo $this->partial('/../../../../vendor/myvendor/library/MyVendor/View/Views/FormPartial.phtml'
, array(...));
```

Any ideas how to link to my vendor directory from my view?

Comment: Have you tried the addBasePath()? I think you can use it to add a path where your view script will be looked for ... so you should be able to use the view without such a long path again and again

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The problem is the resolver can't resolve the path of the view template you had provided. I usually add a configuration entry for all accessible partials in the **template_map** entry in the module.config.php

for example
I have header and footer partials like this my view/layout/header.phtml and view/layout/footer.phtml

below is my config

```
'template_map' => array(
    'layout/layout'         => __DIR__ . '/../view/layout/layout.phtml',
    'header'                => __DIR__ . '/../view/layout/header.phtml',
    'footer'                => __DIR__ . '/../view/layout/footer.phtml',
    'error/404'             => __DIR__ . '/../view/error/404.phtml',
    'error/index'           => __DIR__ . '/../view/error/index.phtml',
),
```

and inside my layout view script I simply put

```
<?php echo $this->partial('header'); ?>
```

and

```
<?php echo $this->partial('footer'); ?>
```

Another if you have your partials under /module/controller/action format you can also do

```
<?php echo $this->partial('/module/controller/action'); ?>
```

you should place the view script in the view folder of your module's controller folder

Comment: Thanks for this detailed answer. but IS there a way to put the partial in a central place where several modules can access it?

Comment: In zf2 any partial defined in config or in any module is equally accessible in any modules as defined above.

If you want to have it in a central place the best place would be your application view folder. place all your partials under partialfoldername/yourpartial.phtml
then you can access your partial as defined by method 2 as '/application/partialfoldername/yourpartial'

Note: choose the partialfoldername  such that it doesn't match with your any defined controllers